# Template subclass scope resolution

Tags: c++, templates

I have a very simple template class.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Test
{
protected:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node(Node& node) {}
    protected:
        virtual Node* copyNode(Node&);
    private:
    };
};

template <class T>
Test<T>::Node* Test<T>::copyNode(Test<T>::Node& node)
{
    return new Test<T>::Node(node);
}
```

I use it in the main program as follows.

```
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Test<int> tree;
    getchar();
}
```

I get a syntax error C2061: "identifier 'Node'".

Both the declaration and the implementation are in the same header file (the linker has problems with template classes). I am using Visual Studio 2015.

What is the proper way of implementing the `copyNode` method without writing it inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typename` are missing:

```
template <class T>
typename Test<T>::Node* Test<T>::Node::copyNode(typename Test<T>::Node& node)
{
    return new Test<T>::Node(node);
}
```

Comment: Also `Node::` is missing before `copyNode`.

Comment: `copyNode()` is declared in scope of `Node`.

Comment: @LogicStuff: stopped by the first error, miss that one :/ fixed.